# ORACLE- Precision and scale of a numeric parameter

Tags: oracle, delphi, stored-procedures

I have a Delphi application database of which is in Oracle. 
Now there's a stored procedure, it's got an `IN` parameter called `PARAM1` of `NUMBER` datatype.

As I assume we can't specify precision and scale for parameters. But this way on Delphi side the parameter appears as float. 
In fact I need it as an integer.

What do I need to do for that?

Comment: Are you able to amend the stored procedure? If so, just amend the parameter to accept `PARAM1` as an `INTEGER` datatype.

Comment: Is not the value returned by `Trunc(aFloat)` function correct?

Comment: What version of Delphi and what access components are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In general, you can use `%TYPE` to specify a "restricted" data type for a parameter. If your parameter is of integer data type, then specify `BINARY_INTEGER` or `PLS_INTEGER` as parameter data type.
2. The client side data type (`TParam.DataType`) depends on the data access components, Oracle and even Delphi versions. Best to provide this info.
3. `ftFloat` data type cons - it may lead to precision lost. If that is the issue, the you can set `DataType` by hands. Also you can use `AsXxxx` parameter properties to assign a parameter value more comfortably.

Comment: Parameters defined as `%type` do not enforce the length and precision of the source column.